# VSCode - Importing keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on **Windows** and **Ubuntu** and I'd like to have the same keyboard shortcuts in both environment (saving my brain memory space for more useful stuff than hotkeys!). Is there a way to **export** the keyboard shortcut settings in one environment and **import** them in the other? Or any other way to uniformize them?

For example, auto-indent on Ubuntu is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, whereas on Windows, it's <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. I'd like to have the same for both.

Comment: Try it https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Comment: I installed this extension, thanks for the recommendation. However, it doesn't seem to sync the core keybindings, only the personalized ones. Or maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: What about this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)?
It was mentioned, 
"If your keyboard shortcuts are platform-agnostic, you can synchronize them across platforms by disabling the setting `settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform`"

Answer (score 6):

you can use this extension [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)  this will sync extensions and complete User Folder that Contains

1. Settings File
2. Keybinding File
3. Launch File
4. Snippets Folder
5. VSCode Extensions & Extensions Configurations
6. Workspaces Folder

it will save all setting on Github gits then you will be able on other platforms to download that setting this will keep to vscode sync it looks like visual studio kind sync but so far the configuration for the first time need little of work but it's not a big deal at totally helpful extensions

**extension features**

1. Use your GitHub account token and Gist.
2. Easy to Upload and Download on one click.
3. Show a summary page at the end with details about config and extensions effected.
4. Auto download Latest Settings on Startup.
5. Auto upload Settings on file change.
6. Share the Gist with other users and let them download your settings.
7. Supports GitHub Enterprise
8. Support pragmas with @sync keywords: host, os, and env are supported.
9. GUI for changing settings / logging in
10. Allows you to Sync any file across your machines.

**Upload Your Settings**

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (macOS: Shift + Option + U)

> Type ">Sync" In Command Palette into order download / upload

When downloading or uploading for the first time, the welcome page will automatically open, where you can configure the Settings Sync.

Once you select to upload, after uploading the settings. You will see the Summary details with the list of each file and extensions uploaded.

**Download your Settings**

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (macOS: Shift + Option + D)

> Type ">Sync" In Command Palette into order download / upload

When downloading or uploading for the first time, the welcome page will automatically open, where you can configure the Settings Sync.

Once you select download, after downloading. Settings Sync will display your Summary containing the list of each file and extension being downloaded.

A new popup will be opened to allow you to restart the code to apply the settings.

**Reset Extension Settings**

> Select "> Sync : Reset Extension Settings" in the Command Palette to
>   reset your settings

so far this feature has been discussed on GitHub and a lot of people recommend  [**Settings Sync**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) extension, maybe in feature versions will has settings sync build in, you can check this open issue [[Ideas] - Settings Sync Roadmap](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/issues/1092) and this [Provide support to synchronize settings across machines](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2743).

Answer (score 3):

As an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57810479/2659307) to a similar question, I made a VSCode extension that provides the default Windows keybindings on any platform.  It is on the [VSCode extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode), and called [Windows Default Keybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smcpeak.default-keys-windows).

If you're happy with the Windows defaults, that should do what you want.

If you want a different platform's bindings (Linux or Mac), you could use the same procedure I did to make that extension, namely, run "Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" and stuff the result into the appropriate place in `package.json` in a new extension.

Comment: This plugin is very helpful! Thanks for giving this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** I think use [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) like [Muhammed Albarmavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332365/9787887) mentioned is the way to go, I used it **myself to sync between Ubuntu and Windows**.

---

However, I don't know if there's a difference in syncing from Linux to Macos. About [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync), the idea is it uses [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) to store all the settings on the cloud, so that then you could use any machine to pull (download) from the cloud to replicate those settings on any new machine. With the extension, you **just need to press upload/download**, all the copying process is **done by the extension for you**.

Details about those files store on `gist`, they're:

- extensions.json
- `keybindings.json`
- `keybindingsMac.json`
- settings.json
- snippets|javascript.json
- ...another modified settings
- You could take a look about its shape here: https://gist.github.com/loia5tqd001/7f68a682472a018bcc75ecadeeab447b

As you can see, there're `keybindings.json` and `keybindingsMac.json`, I would guess `keybindings.json` is for linux and windows, and `keybindingsMac.json` is for Macos, the other settings (like `extensions settings`) would be the same. So I myself keep syncing between Ubuntu and Windows by changing the same file `keybindings.json`. About syncing from Linux to MacOs, I don't know exactly what's happening under the hood, give a look at [a comment here](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/issues/194#issuecomment-276562844) maybe you'll know. But the exactly what's happening under the hood seems to be not very important because it's taken care of by the Settings Sync itself already, so you might just try pressing upload and download, and see the changes happen.

As you use the Settings Sync, you'll notice that **you can have [multiple gists](https://gist.github.com/loia5tqd001)**, so you can have multiple versions of settings on the cloud. Maybe you'd want **some gist for Windows**, **some for Linux/macOS** or any strategy that you could think of.

But if you want the exact same settings from the default ones to the modified ones syncing across the machines, I think **that might not how it could work**. But think, for example, to duplicate a line of code (copy-lines-down-action), the default key-shortcut would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, and **it works well on Windows, but not on Ubuntu** because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is also the default shortcut for moving between workspaces of the OS, so it'll not work on Ubuntu. The point is, **the different OS is different**, so you might not just copying the exact same settings from an OS to another and hope it'll work perfectly the same too easily. But I promise, using [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) would not be that very painful, just a little tweak of OS-difference settings along the way, then you'll be happy.

If you haven't known how to use Settings Sync yet, I suggest just watch a youtube video, a medium article and/or the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync). Still, it'll be fairly easy.

If there's a better way to sync perfectly exact settings from an OS to another btw, I would be curious to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import key bindings from other code editors like Atom or Sublime, there are plugins which you can directly install and start using. Hope that helped :)