# How to transfer VSCode key mapping on windows to ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use vs-code as my go-to editor on Windows. Recently I've installed on Ubuntu and now the default key mapping is different.

Is there any way I can set the key mapping on Ubuntu similar to what they were for Windows, or at least a subset of it?

Comment: @odyn-Kon any doubt in question?

Comment: Very similar to question [VSCode - Importing keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840945/vscode-importing-keyboard-shortcuts), which I spent some time researching but didn't find a satisfactory answer.  The default bindings are hardcoded in the source, making them challenging to extract automatically, and have many differences across platforms.  My approach is to just explicitly customize everything I use...

Comment: @ScottMcPeak `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command looks promising.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes!  I hadn't seen that before.  Just to be extra clear, that is available in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Comment: What about this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)?
It was mentioned, 
"If your keyboard shortcuts are platform-agnostic, you can synchronize them across platforms by disabling the setting `settingsSync.keybindingsPerPlatform`"

Answer (score 62):

I have created an extension that provides the default Windows keybindings.  It is on the [VSCode extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) and called [Windows Default Keybindngs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smcpeak.default-keys-windows).

I have tested it on Linux with VSCode 1.38.0 and 1.36.1.

The new bindings take precedence where there is a conflict, but existing, non-conflicting bindings are still available.

Basically all I did was use HolyBlackCat's suggestion to run "Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" and stuff the result into the appropriate place in `package.json`.  (Plus document it and figure out how to publish it!)

Update 2020-06-05: In response to a question in a comment, I did a search and found [LinuxKeybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fredhappyface.linuxkeybindings), an extension that provides the default Linux bindings.  I have not tried it myself but this could be useful for those wanting the Linux bindings instead of Windows bindings.

Comment: Won't there be problems with conflicting shortcuts? From what I understand, this adds additional shortcuts, but doesn't remove existing ones.

Comment: Right, it does not remove anything.  When there is a conflict, only the binding from my extension is used; at least, that is what I observe in my testing.  I initially thought I might have to unbind some existing keys, but as far as I can tell, that is unnecessary.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak do you know any extesion that does the opposite? Im used to VSCode Linux keybind, and now i'm trying the WSL2 and would like to keep using my old ones..

Comment: @JoãoRamires I just did a search and found a promising candidate, LinuxKeybindings.  See the paragraph I just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: In ubuntu 22 I had to run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['']"
` so ctrl-alt- arrows shortcuts would work

Answer (score 13):

A quick way to transfer the default keymap without an extension:

#### VS Code Windows (source)

- open "Show All Commands" / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- select `Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_default-keyboard-shortcuts))

  [image]

  *Note*: [@Ville Venäläinen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727041/5669456) did not work for me for default key bindings.
- copy everthing to clipboard or a temporary file (like you need it)

#### VS Code Linux (target)

- open user keybindings / <kbd>CTRL + K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL + S</kbd> → click `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` button

  [image]
- paste all previously copied settings to this file. If you already have custom user settings, make sure to don't overwrite them. Also preserve the file JSON structure `[{}, {}, ...]`.

---

#### Additional notes

You can make a backup of the keymaps before. Default file locations analogue to [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

```
Linux: $HOME/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\keybindings.json
```

If needed, also copy custom user keyboard shortcuts in source and append them in the target `keybindings.json` file (as explained above).

This worked well for me with a Debian target distro. If you should happen to get a key conflict, just delete or change the relevant key binding for this case.

Answer (score 5):

At least with the latest VSCode, you can go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. On that page, there is a text under the search field: For advanced customizations open and edit keybindings.json. That will open you a view showing the default keybindings on the left and an empty file on the right for your own bindings. You can try to copy those bindings from Windows and save the to your Ubuntu one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your time. But I am looking for some sort of extension for this because I don't want to maintain a custom setting for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not customizing your keymap, look through [VSCode Keymaps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Keymaps&sortBy=Downloads) for keymaps and install on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I like the default keybinding of vscode which are in windows, I need the same keybinding on Linux also. But unfortunately, I haven't come across any extension which does that.

Comment: so there is lots of pain remembering two set of keybinding furthermore my habit I presses some wrong keys and something wired happens.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use the [code-settings-sync](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync) extension.

> Synchronize Settings, Snippets, Themes, File Icons, Launch, Keybindings, Workspaces and Extensions Across Multiple Machines Using GitHub Gist.